# Hide small images of product on frontend Magento 2

Tags: image, magento2

I have Magento 2 and want to hide small images of the product that is added from the admin on frontend. 
I have hidden the small image attribute from admin but want to hide it from front-end as well.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Add a single image to Product that is only one image to Product and on frontend you will not see the small images